# Are Google Sheets filters secure enough to share with multiple clients?

Tags: google-sheets, security

I have a .csv that I import into Google Sheets. This contains data for multiple clients. Right now, I have to manually split this sheet into different workbooks/files and share each individual file with each different client. Each client then receives a file with only their data in it.

I would like to reduce my workload and set up filters with restricted permissions so that I can just share one file with all of my clients. They can then only use the filter I have shared with them and there is only one file to manage.

Is this plan completely foolproof? (hold the laughter)

Comment: Hell no. Any data shared is retrievable. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69964587

Answer (score 1):

### Option-A

Personally, I would recommend you set up a [webapp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) / cllient dashboard. This way they are given a personalized url that with automatically pull just their data up. This is all assuming ofcourse that theres not a huge concern for privacy as it is over the web.

### Option-B

Another option, which I had designed for myself when I was trying to build a B2B market place is to have a *MAIN* spreadsheet, your eyes only, you then create a new *CLIENT* spreadsheet from a preformmated & configured *template* and have it pull the specific relevant data from your *MAIN* sheet. Then you can share their data in their own spreadsheet.

### Option-C

Then there is Googles [Looker Studio](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/looker-next-evolution-business-intelligence-data-studio), I can't really speak to it but it's predicessor 'Data Studio' made it easy to create front end User pages with data and had all the fancy tools but you can pretty much accomplish the same thing with sheets alone and Google Sites if SHeets is the only source of Data to worry about

Comment: Even option B is not secure if script is bound to spreadsheet. Option A maybe secure depending on web dev skills. +1 for option A

Comment: Correct. these are definately not Enterprise grade solutions but for a small business it can keep things organized.